# How do I add a custom share option in iMovie?

Tags: macos, video, content-management-system, imovie

The Mac's OS X iMovie has built-in share options (like YouTube, iTunes, MobileMe, etc.).  I currently develop a video-oriented content management system, and **I would like to add "share" functionality to iMovie for my CMS**, even if the installation is painful or 'hacky'.  There does not seem to be an API, but maybe there is?  Or maybe the menus are scripted and hidden in plain sight?  Or???

- iMovie '08 (7.1.4 585)
- OS X (10.5.6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iMovie '08 (and iMovie '09) does not allow third party plugins.  I believe the last version of iMovie that allowed third party plugins was iMovie HD.

Comment: Sad, but true apparently.  Apple did this when they dropped the price of FinalCut Express to US$100.  Sounds like the magic of marketing strikes again.

Answer (score 2):

There appears to be a plugin folder inside the iMovie bundle called RADPlugins.  I would suggest using something like [class-dump](http://iphone.freecoder.org/classdump_en.html) on them and see what it is they are doing.  You might be able to get your code into iMovie that way.  Be warned however that you would be using completely undocumented APIs so every new release of iMovie could (will) break your plugin.

I have produced a plugin for the Mac OS X Mail app for some years now, and every release has broken something ;)

Comment: That's just a bit too far out of my comfort zone, but thanks for the idea.  +1